# Salesforce crashing on ios9/10

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I've just implemented salesforce for iOS v5.1.0 and published to the store, but now im getting crash reports that only iOS 9 /10 users and only iPhone 5 / 5c / 4s are crashing on launch.

When I send the version via xcode, it works fine but when uploaded to the App Store it simply crashes.
Here is the log, any help?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1dcdbb3d __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1cf63067 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x1fc43399 +[_PFLock initialize]
3  myapp                       0x47eb85 -[SFMCDatabase persistentStoreCoordinator] (SFMCDatabase.m:254)
4  myapp                       0x47ce4b -[SFMCDatabase setupContexts] (SFMCDatabase.m:27)
5  myapp                       0x4649b3 -[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation setupWithConfiguration:error:] (MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m:202)
6  myapp                       0x3c32d3 -[MarketingCloudSDK frameworkHeavyLiftInitialization:completionHandler:configurationIndex:configurationInfo:defaultFrameworks:weakSelf:] (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:115)
7  myapp                       0x3c42eb -[MarketingCloudSDK initializeFrameworks:completionHandler:configurationIndex:configurationInfo:defaultFrameworks:] (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:229)
8  myapp                       0x3c55a7 -[MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configureWithURL:configurationIndex:error:completionHandler:] (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:394)
9  myapp                       0x3c451f -[MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configureWithURL:configurationIndex:error:] (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:245)
10 myapp                       0xea7c1 -[AppDelegate configureMarketingCloud] (AppDelegate.m:344)
11 myapp                       0xe9705 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:127)
12 UIKit                          0x22f7d5c5 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
13 UIKit                          0x2317ea4b -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:]
14 UIKit                          0x23183c1d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
15 UIKit                          0x231967c5 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3149
16 UIKit                          0x2318135b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:]
17 FrontBoardServices             0x1f5bcc13 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
18 FrontBoardServices             0x1f5bcacd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]
19 FrontBoardServices             0x1f5bcdb7 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1dc97fdd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1dc97b05 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1dc95f51 __CFRunLoopRun
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1dbe91af CFRunLoopRunSpecific
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1dbe8fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode
25 UIKit                          0x22f76e2d -[UIApplication _run]
26 UIKit                          0x22f71a53 UIApplicationMain
27 myapp                       0x138607 main (main.m:14)
28 libdyld.dylib                  0x1d3d64eb start
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to v5.1.1 and that should fix the issue.