# salesforce crashing on iPad devices

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush-ios

After integrating Marketing Cloud SDK(v5.0.0) in my iOS app, crashes have been continuously reported for iPad devices(iOS 9/10) on app launch. Any guidance?
Following are the logs from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 0  CoreFoundation             

0x1d277b3d __exceptionPreprocess 1  libobjc.A.dylib
0x1c4ff067 objc_exception_throw 2 CoreData
0x1f1df399 +[_PFLock initialize] 3 Closet
0xb846bd -[SFMCDatabase persistentStoreCoordinator] (SFMCDatabase.m:254) 4 Closet 0xb82983 -[SFMCDatabase setupContexts] (SFMCDatabase.m:27) 5 Closet 0xb6a4eb -[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation setupWithConfiguration:error:] (MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m:202) 6 Closet
0xac8e0f -[MarketingCloudSDK frameworkHeavyLiftInitialization:completionHandler:configurationIndex:configurationInfo:defaultFrameworks:weakSelf:] (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:115) 7 Closet
0xac9ee5 __115-[MarketingCloudSDK initializeFrameworks:completionHandler:configurationIndex:configurationInfo:defaultFrameworks:]_block_invoke (MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:234) 8 libdispatch.dylib
0x1c945797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release 9 libdispatch.dylib
0x1c952b1d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke 10 libdispatch.dylib
0x1c9541b5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain 11 libdispatch.dylib
0x1c95400f _dispatch_worker_thread3 12 libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1cafa87d _pthread_wqthread 13 libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1cafa45c start_wqthread
```

found a similar question:
[Salesforce crashing on ios9/10](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219217/salesforce-crashing-on-ios9-10?newreg=4c7a717f40b94e4b918e02de6b80335e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was addressed in the 5.1.1 release; we just released 5.2.0 last week and it is suggested that you make 5.2.0 your baseline.